# Python 2.7. write following 4 lines out from a huge file

Tags: python, parsing

The huge file goes like this.

```
@delimiter...xxxxxxx     1st line
atgccccccccccccccc...    2nd line
+                        3rd line
agtrc!%%^*()_+!...       4th line
```

Those four lines go on. The delimiter may be in the 1st line. What I want to do is if the delimiter is in the 1st line, I want to write the following 4lines out.

Here is my code.

```
with open("hugefile") as fin, open("hugefile_out") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if delimiter in line:
            1st_line = line
            2nd_line = fin.next()
            3rd_line = fin.next()
            4th_line = fin.next()
            fout.write(1st_line + 2nd_line + 3rd_line + 4th_line)
```

Usually it takes 4 up to 5 hours to get this job done.(I dropped one function.) Is there a way to make it faster?(I use pypy.) The input file is 1~100Gb so those repeated codes seem unnecessary.

maybe like this?

```
           fout.write(line + fin.next() + fin.next() + fin.next())
```

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: what happens if the delimiter is not in the first line?

Comment: I don't need them then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend an approach like the following:

1. Use a *flag* to indicate that you've seen a delimiter and are currently in the process of outputting lines
2. Use an *index* to know how many lines you've output
3. Stop outputting lines once the *index* is > 4 and reset the *flag* to false (alternatively, if you only want to find one set, you could bail out of the iteration entirely)

So, the code would then be something like this:

```
sawDelim = False
idx = 1
with open("hugefile") as fin, open("hugefile_out") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if delimiter in line:
            sawDelim = True

        if sawDelim:               
            fout.write(line)
            idx += 1

        # now that we've printed out 4 lines, reset and keep looking
        # (or could also bail if you want to only find one set)
        if (idx > 4):
            idx = 1
            sawDelim = False
```

Comment: Another approach: have one variable for number of lines to output after this one. If you see the delimiter, set it to four. Each time you output a line, decrement it.